# how to solve when zoomed the bottom container is not follow top navigation bar at the center? CSS

Tags: css

[zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSjKq.jpg)

[default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Hon.jpg)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
body {
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: #7A797A;
}
.Content_container {
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
#header {
 padding: 20px 0 60px 0;
}
#Logo img {
 float: left;
 margin: 5px 10px 10px 2px;
 padding: 5px 10px 10px 2px;
}
#Nav {
 float: left;
 width: 750px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 70px 0 20px 60px;
}
#Nav ul {
 float: right;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#Nav ul li {
 padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
 float: left;
}
#Nav ul li a {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #7A797A;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
}
#Nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #353435;
 line-height: 10px;
}
#Nav ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#Nav ul li a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
#NailArt {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive; 
 color: rgba(245,166,200,1);
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 960px;
}
#N1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 480px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #FEF3F7 no-repeat fixed 100%;
 background-size: cover;
}
#Nail1 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
 padding: 50px 0 50px 160px;
 width: 960px;
 height: 400px;
}
#Nail2 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
 padding: 50px 0 50px 160px;
 width: 960px;
 height: 400px;
}
#N3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 480px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #FEF3F7 no-repeat fixed 100%;
 background-size: cover;
}
#Nail3 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
 padding: 50px 0 50px 160px;
 width: 960px;
 height: 400px;
}
#Nail1 h2, #Nail2 h2, #Nail3 h2 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; 
    color: rgba(245,166,200,1);
 margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
#Nail2 h2 {
 padding: 0 0 0 560px;
}
#Nail1 p, #Nail3 p {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 float: left;
 margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
 width: 400px;
}
#Nail2 p {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 float: right;
 margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
 width: 400px;
}
#Nail1 img, #Nail3 img {
 float: right;
 margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
#Nail2 img {
 float: left;
 margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
#Nail1 img, #Nail2 img, #Nail3 img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

#Nail1 img::, #Nail2 img::, #Nail3 img::after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

#Nail1 img:hover, #Nail2 img:hover, #Nail3 img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

#Nail1 img:hover::, #Nail2 img:hover::, #Nail3 img:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
#Footer {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: right;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 clear: both;
 width: 960px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 56px 0 0 159px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Simple Nail | Nail Art</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,800,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic|Abril+Fatface|Libre+Baskerville:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="Styles/Simple Nail Nail Art Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="Images/snlogo icon.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Images/nail1.1.jpg','Images/nail2.2.jpg','Images/nail3.3.jpg')">
<div id="Container">
  <div id="Header">
    <div class="Content_container">
      <div id="Logo"><a href="Simple Nail Web.html"><img src="Images/snlogo.png" width="100" height="100" /></a></div><!--End of Logo -->
      <div id="Nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Simple Nail Web.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Simple Nail About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="Simple Nail Nail Art.html">Nail Art</a></li>
          <li><a href="Simple Nail Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--End of Nav -->
    </div><!--End of Content_container -->
  </div><!--End of Header -->
    <div id="Content">
    <div id="NailArt">
      <h1>Nail Art</h1>
    </div><!--End of NailArt -->
    <div id="N1">
    <div id="Nail1">
      <h2>Dots</h2>
      <p>Those days are gone when single nail color could make it; people use to buy main colors likes pink, red, blue, yellow and applied them straight away on nails to make beautiful nail art patterns. Girls treat their hands as that of princesses who would take all the gems that make them pretty. This is a simple step by step Polka Dots nail art tutorials for beginners & learners. Have a look at the tutorials to learn the right and exact techniques of Polka Dots nail art application.</p>
      <a href="Simple Nail Dots.html"><img src="Images/nail1.jpg" width="400" height="300" id="Image1" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image1','','Images/nail1.1.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></a></div><!--End of Nail1 -->
    </div><!--End of N1 -->
    <div id="N2">
    <div id="Nail2">
      <h2>Lines & Boxes</h2>
      <p>If you want your nails art in different shapes like lines, stripes or boxes, this tutorial will give you a bomb. As you can just do the manicure fast as you can. It is easy and simple! Here are some techniques that will make the complicated world of nail art seem a lot less daunting. This is a simple step by step Lines & Boxes nail art tutorials for beginners & learners. Have a look at the tutorials to learn the right and exact techniques of Lines & Boxes nail art application.</p>
      <a href="Simple Nail Line.html"><img src="Images/nail2.jpg" width="400" height="300" id="Image2" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image2','','Images/nail2.2.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></a></div><!--End of Nail2 -->
    </div><!--End of N2 -->
    <div id="N3">
    <div id="Nail3">
      <h2>Sharpie Art</h2>
      <p>If you have a hard enough time applying a single coat without making a smeary mess.Here are some techniques that will make the complicated world of nail art seem a lot less daunting. You can do you nail art in different shapes or patterns like leopard patterns or some doodle art. It will make your nails look fabulous. Have a look at the tutorials to learn the right and exact techniques of Sharpie Art nail art application.</p>
      <a href="Simple Nail Sharp.html"><img src="Images/nail3.jpg" width="400" height="300" id="Image3" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image3','','Images/nail3.3.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></a></div><!--End of Nail3 -->
    </div><!--End of N3 -->
  </div><!--end of Content -->
<div id="Footer">COPYRIGHT &copy; 2016 SIMPLE NAIL BY SINZY LSY</div>
  <!--End of Footer -->
</div><!--End of Container -->
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new in CSS, pls give me detailed solution

Im sorry I dont know which part is wrong.

Can I use `position:relative` to solve it or any other method.

Comment: You should first read how to ask question on SO with minimal code you have tried. No one will give you ready made code. Thank you

Comment: Please provide us a code

Comment: okay thx you
i will repost my questions

Comment: @TownKokLim Just edit your question, no need for repost. And let us know in comment section that you've made changes .

Comment: Are you serious with the x's?

Comment: sorry for that
because it require me to enter smtg

Answer (score 0):

By adding "margin: auto;" to your body divs like (.#N1),
you will place the div in the middle of the screen. Exactly like your nav bar.